# Python Socket Programming - ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061]

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to establish a simple TCP Client-Server connection but there is an exception I'm not able to fix.

This is my server

```
   from socket import *
serverPort = 1200
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind('',serverPort)
print('Server has started: '+str(serverPort))
print('Server is ready to accept requests: ')
while 1:
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept();
    print('Klienti u lidh me serverin %s me port $s' % addr)
    fjalia = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
    FjaliaMeShkronjaTeMedha = fjalia.upper()
    print(FjaliaMeShkronjaTeMedha)
    connectionSocket.send(FjaliaMeShkronjaTeMedha)
    connectionSocket.close()
```

and this is my client:

```
import socket
serverName = 'localhost'
serverPort = 1200
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((serverName,serverPort)) #here is the error
var = input("jeni lidhur me serverin, shkruaje kerkesen")
s.sendall(str.encode(var))
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print('te dhenat e pranuara nga serveri',repr(data))
```

however, at the client in this particular piece the connection is being refused

```
 s.connect((serverName,serverPort)) #here is the error
```

and this is the exception [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFxdP.png)

Could anyone tell me why is this happening? I'm a newbie to sockets
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did your server run without errors?

Comment: @EJP yes, the problem is on the client's side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issues With Code**  :

Your server is not accepting any connections that is why you see this error.
Your server implementation has some issue let me high light those for you .
first off serverSocket.bind('',serverPort) call is incorrect you should change it to serverSocket.bind(('',serverPort)) a tuple 
Secondly your socket must be in listen mode to listen in bound connections.

**Here is the fixed code  :**

**For Server**

```
from socket import *
serverPort = 1200
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind(('',serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(10)
print('Server has started: '+str(serverPort))
print('Server is ready to accept requests: ')
while 1:
     client_sock, address = serverSocket.accept()
     print('Klienti u lidh me serverin {0} me port $s'.format( address))
     fjalia = client_sock.recv(1024)
     FjaliaMeShkronjaTeMedha = fjalia.upper()
     print(FjaliaMeShkronjaTeMedha)
     client_sock.send(FjaliaMeShkronjaTeMedha)
     client_sock.close()
```

**For Client Side**

```
import socket
serverName = 'localhost'
serverPort = 1200
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((serverName,serverPort)) #here is the error
var = b"jeni lidhur me serverin, shkruaje kerkesen"
s.sendall((var))
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print('te dhenat e pranuara nga serveri',repr(data))
```

**Output from server side**

```
Server has started: 1200
Server is ready to accept requests: 
Klienti u lidh me serverin ('127.0.0.1', 54722) me port $s
JENI LIDHUR ME SERVERIN, SHKRUAJE KERKESEN
```

**Output from client side**

```
te dhenat e pranuara nga serveri b'JENI LIDHUR ME SERVERIN, SHKRUAJE KERKESEN'
```

hope this helps

Comment: The output on the server side is working, but on the client side the error persists, I'm not getting an output

Comment: @BleronQorri what do you expect at client side ? this is the print on client side `print('te dhenat e pranuara nga serveri',repr(data))`  the data sent from sever side is same as it was sent by client before

Comment: I am expecting the same thing you got, but I'm not getting it, I don't know why, the code is correct

Comment: get ip of your machineusing `ipconfig` on windows or `ifconfig` it you are on linux. Then . Make the following changes in code 
`serverSocket.bind(('yourIP',serverPort)) `in server file and `serverName = 'yourIP'` in client side .
for the record you need to run server first and do not quit the server , and then run client with server already running.